# Find the volume below $z = \sqrt{1 - r^{2}}$ and above the top half of the cone $z = r$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I have made an attempt at this question:

> Find the volume below $z = \sqrt{1 - r^{2}}$ and above the top half of the cone $z = r$

I solved for $r$ first, then I calculated:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}}r\sqrt{1-r^{2}}drd\theta = -\frac{1}{6}\pi(\sqrt{2} - 4)
\end{equation}
I wasn't sure of my answer and after plotting the surfaces in Geogebra I'm sure that my inner integral bounds are incorrect, can anybody provide any guidance? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $z = \sqrt{1 - z^{2}}$, then $z$ must be $1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: don't you need to subtract $z=r$ like  $r\left(\sqrt{1-r^2}-r\right)drd\theta $

Comment: @Lozenges Great suggestion, I've calculated the integral using this function and the same bounds  but I'm not sure how to know if it's correct. My problem with this question in particular lies with if I've chosen the correct bounds for the inner integral, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Without integrating: The region is bounded above by a plane and below by a cone, so it's just the [volume of a right cone with height and radius $\frac1{\sqrt2}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=volume+of+cone+with+radius+1%2Fsqrt2+and+height+1%2Fsqrt2). With integrating: $\sqrt{1-r^2}$ shouldn't be there. The upper bounding surface is the plane $z=\frac1{\sqrt2}$, so you should be integrating $r\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}-r\right)$. Meanwhile $z=\sqrt{1-r^2}=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ is the top half of a sphere, not a plane.

Comment: @user170231 Thanks, this makes sense.

Comment: So there is no typo after all. The equation in the title is indeed $z=\sqrt{1-z^2}$ and not $z=\sqrt{1-r^2}$

Comment: @Lozenges My apologies. I overlooked your message, I've edited the post

Comment: No problem. Integrate $r\left(\sqrt{1-r^2}-r\right)$. Your bounds for the integral are correct